# Can't open Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 (Error launching program)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have a desktop shortcut that's supposed to run eclipse

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

The Icon is just the txt icon and it says Error launching program

Also when I try to run eclipse by double clicking the executable nothing happens at all

When I put /opt/eclipse/eclipse in the terminal I get this output.

[image: terminal output]

Comment: What does the log say when you run `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` in a Terminal?  Any reason you installed Eclipse in a non-standard way?

Comment: I downloaded the package and unzipped it to that location. When I run the command nothing happens. I thought oh maybe I have to wait. I waited over an hour and it never launched

Comment: Actually I lied it output something this time ill paste it in a second

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I added the output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded a 32-bit version of Eclipse.  This will not run with a 64-bit JVM (long story, native libraries).

Remove your current Eclipse, download a 64-bit version of Eclipse and redo the whole installation.  Note that you need Java 8 for the Eclipse version you want to run now, and that may not be easily available for Ubuntu 12.04.  Get Java 8 running first or get an older version of Eclipse or update to Ubuntu 14.04 and then Ubuntu 16.04 which has OpenJDK 8 which will do.

Note:  These days Eclipse really want you to use their installer.  You may want to do that.  If you download a zip file anyway, just unzip it and run the eclipse binary.  You do not have to put it in /opt unless you want to share with other users on your machine.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn’t realize I had a 64 bit. I’m using a chrome book so i couldn’t really find out which it was so I decided to wing it and go for the 32